# Child bash identical to invoking parent

Tags: bash, computing-environment

Is it possible to invoke a bash such that **everything** about my environment (aliases, function, exported/non-exported variables, etc) will be present in the new shell?

I'd settle for just getting the shell variables that aren't part of my environment. I run `bash --norc` and the first thing I notice is I've lost $PS1 and my `ls` colours. I could simply export those variables before calling `bash`, but I'm worried about the whole slew of other things I might miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into the `alias` and `set` command.  If run without parameters, `alias` will list all defined parameters and `set` will list all variables and functions.  Pushing the output of these commands to a temporary file and then telling bash to read this file as an rc file *may* accomplish what your looking for.

Comment: This is the closest I've been yet, but I've finally accepted that what I _really_ want is impossible. I want to write a Perl script that sets my environment. It would do some stuff, set some variables, and finally `exec bash`. I can't afford to let the environment be tainted by rc init files, but I want things like ls coloring and a descent PS1. I think maybe my best bet is to have the Perl script print the environment changes, and have the user invoke it with back ticks.

Comment: depending on the complexity of the perl script, have it write it's own temporary rc file and then invoke bash with:

bash --rcfile <path-to-the-temp-rc-file>

This will not load the system wide or user rc file, only the file specified.

Comment: I was part way through doing exactly that when I realized the script won't have access to its parent's aliases and function - only its environment.

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can, however, enable auto-export of functions and variables by adding `set -a` at the top of your `rc` script.